# Structures and pointers in C

Tags: c

I'm creating a structure inside a function and then returning its pointer. For some reason I keep getting the same memory address each time.

```
typedef struct list_type
{
    node_t *head;
    node_t *tail;
} list_t;

list_t newList() {
    list_t list = {NULL, NULL};
    list_t *listptr = &list;
    printf("newList: %p\n", listptr);
    return listptr;
}
```

Outputs:

```
newList: 0x7fffb42c8ae0
newList: 0x7fffb42c8ae0
newList: 0x7fffb42c8ae0
```

What am I doing?...

Comment: Read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You got one.

Comment: For one, `list_t*` isn't `list_t`. The compiler should have at-least warned you of this. If it didn't, ram up your warning level.

Comment: This code shouldn't compile as you return `list_t*` while have `list_t` in definition.

Comment: Looks like you come from a javascript or python background -- C does not work the same way -- you need to explicitly allocate your structures if you want to use them the way you do.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The code he has contains no undefined behavior. OP has not shown any code that actually uses the pointer returned (which could be undefined behavior).

Answer (score 3):

You are allocating `list` on the stack, but you're trying to return a reference to it from a function. This is a big no-no in C, since the struct's memory is automatically freed by the compiler when it goes out of scope. If you want memory to persist beyond the scope it is allocated in, you need to use `malloc`.

Furthermore, `list_t` and a pointer to it (`list_t*`) are two different types, and you need to indicate that as such in your function definition.

```
list_t* newList() {
    list_t *listptr = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    printf("newList: %p\n", listptr);
    return listptr;
}
```

However, be careful when using `malloc`. Since you're allocating memory manually, you'll now need to ensure that you call `free` on the pointer when you're done with it, or it will leak, since the compiler cannot free the memory for you.

Answer (score 3):

`list_t list = {NULL, NULL};`
allocates memory on stack. Memory allocated on stack is automatically freed when the variable, list in your case, goes out of scope.
That is why you are getting the same address again and again as memory allocated to list on stack gets freed when program comes out of function `newList()` and is available for allocation. And, when you call the `newList()` again, same memory is alloacted again.

You should read about different memory allocations and pay more attention to the compiler warnings.

Comment: +1 for pay more attention to the compiler warnings..

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a pointer to an object allocated on the stack. If you use the value that the pointer points to in the function that calls `newList()`, you'll cause undefined behavior to occur.

You should read about **malloc()** and **free()**.

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns a `list_t`, a structure type, which is perfectly fine by-value. I see no evidence you're trying to dynamically allocate a `list_t`, and no evidence you even *need to do so*.

Lose the pointer stuff *for this specific structure type* entirely and just do this:

```
list_t newList() 
{
    list_t list = {NULL, NULL};
    return list;
}

void freeList(list_t lst)
{
    // TODO: delete lst nodes by walking lst.head through lst.tail
}

int main()
{
    list_t lst = newList();

    ...

    freeList(lst);
}
```

Don't step into the arena of managing dynamic memory because you *can*; do it when you *need to do so*, and in this case, you don't. You *obviously* need to in order to manage the actual list *nodes*, but thats a different issue than this one.